# Replacing a ballast

Tags: light, fluorescent, ballast

I replaced a ballast in a fluorescent fixture I put a new bulb in and it turned on. I put a second new bulb in and it didn’t turn on so i twisted the first bulb so it turned off. the second bulb that I put in now turns on. is this a bad ballast?

Comment: Are you sure you purchased the right ballast for your lights?  Make sure you wired it correctly.

Comment: There are so many wiring configurations that to answer this we would need to see the label, the fixture wires at the end plates, all wire connectors, and the lamps in use.

Comment: Have you turned the power off and back on with both lamps in? Some electronic ballasts have independent safety’s that need to be reset with a power cycle.

Comment: Are the bulbs you using listed on the ballast's label?  How did you wire the new ballast (i.e. did you follow the drawing on the ballast's label)?  Photos would let us cross-check all that stuff.

Comment: Skip replacing ballasts and switch to LED lamps that replace fluorescents.